# Lag between Fed Announcement and Actual Implementation

Tags: federal-reserve, yield-curve

After the Fed announces its new target range for Fed Funds, is there a set number of days before actual implementation?

If not, is there a convention, like within a week?

I'm wondering, because the Fed announced the new range of 3.00-3.25% on September 21, but as of end-of-day, September 22, the Treasury shows a 1M T-Bill rate of 2.73%, indicating that the new range hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: The new target Fed funds rate is effective immediately. Treasury yields are driven by market dynamics, the Fed doesn't set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fed announces its new target range for Fed Funds...
>
> ...I'm wondering,
> because the Fed announced the new range of 3.00-3.25% on September 21,
> but as of end-of-day, September 22, the Treasury shows a 1M T-Bill
> rate of 2.73%, indicating that the new range hasn't been implemented
> yet.

They don't set the rate for T-Bills.

From their [Implementation Note issued September 21, 2022](https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/monetary20220921a1.htm)

> The Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System voted unanimously
> to raise the interest rate paid on reserve balances to 3.15 percent,
> effective September 22, 2022.

Banks are required to have funds held in reserve. When one bank is a little short, and another has some excess reserves, this the rate that the funds are borrowed.

> [Effective Federal Funds Rate](https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/reference-rates/effr)
>
> The federal funds market consists of domestic unsecured borrowings in
> U.S. dollars by depository institutions from other depository
> institutions and certain other entities, primarily
> government-sponsored enterprises.

T-bills and the like aren't set by the federal reserve. They are set via auction.